# Playing RTSP Audio stream

Tags: android, streaming, audio-player

I am trying to play RTSP stream with URL format like rtsp://xxxxxxxx.sdp
Many people are trying to play RTSP video stream in Android some try with intent and some with video view like below code

```
video1=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
video1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://208.77.20.52:1935/dmm1/ten"));
video1.requestFocus();
video1.start();
```

Is it possible to play audio stream in Android using `MediaPlayer` object? If yes, Please provide some solution for that I have an audio stream working fine on VLC but does not work in Android.

Below is the code what I have tried for audio stream from RTSP in Android

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(RTSPurl);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Here is full code I am trying:

```
 public class Radio extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

String rtspUrl = "rtsp://192.168.9.59:8080/test.sdp";
MediaPlayer player;
Context c;

public Radio(Context c) {
    this.c = c;
    Log.i("TAG","Initializing...");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    player.start();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.start();
            Toast.makeText(c, "starting..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


}

private void setDataSource(String path2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {

        Uri a = Uri.parse(rtspUrl);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource(c, a);
        player.prepareAsync();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setDataSource(rtspUrl);

    Log.e("inside doinbackground....", rtspUrl);
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: you are doing it right. You only need to specify stream type also `soundPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`

Comment: I tried with that as well but seems no effect.I have pasted my all code in original post.Please check that.

Comment: I have found the concluding point. sdp format is not supported by android player directly.

Comment: so what is the format ?